# blocking user after clicking button more than 3 times

Tags: delphi

I want to block a user from clicking a button again after they have clicked the button more than 3 times. the flow of actions follows

1. user clicks the button
2. Code is displayed to user
3. User gets the opportunity to enter the code in the edit box again
4. if user requested a new code by clicking the button more than 3 times they will be restricted from clicking the button again.

```pascal
procedure TVerifyForm.btnCAPTCHAClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  A: integer;
begin
  // CaptchaForm.ShowModal;
  A := 0;
  Inc(A);
  if A = 3 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('BLOCKED');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What have you done so far? What are your problems to solve it?

Comment: Declaring a counter variable and incrementing / checking against three in the `OnClick` event handler seems like such a trivial task, that I have to ask you whether you forgot to tell the "crux" of your question.

Comment: What does "_to enter the button in the edit box_" mean? One cannot enter a button, not even pirates achieve that.

Comment: @AmigoJack typo

Comment: i wanted to add that some normalo users klick everything 3 times. because it works for everything. (Desktop Icons, Startbutton) But i see your Problem is some time away from User behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You are using a local variable, that will not work in this case.  You need a variable that persists after the `OnClick` handler exits. Make it a member of the button's parent Form.

```pascal
type
  TVerifyForm = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    NumberOfClicks: Integer;
    ...
  end;

procedure TVerifyForm.btnCAPTCHAClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if NumberOfClicks >= 3 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('BLOCKED');
    Exit;
  end
  Inc(NumberOfClicks);
  // CaptchaForm.ShowModal;
  ...
end;
```

Or, you could simply use the button's own `Tag` property instead:

```pascal
procedure TVerifyForm.btnCAPTCHAClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if btnCAPTCHA.Tag >= 3 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('BLOCKED');
    Exit;
  end;
  btnCAPTCHA.Tag := btnCAPTCHA.Tag + 1;
  // CaptchaForm.ShowModal;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: I'd use a safe `as` cast there, just in case.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I generally stay away from invoking the extra overhead of using `as` unless absolutely necessary.  If you *know* for sure that no code other than `btnCAPTCHA` itself could possibly call `btnCAPTCHAClick()` with a different `Sender`, then using the non-`as` type-cast is perfectly safe. If you have other code calling `btnCAPTCHAClick()` directly, then you likely have bigger design issues to worry about.

Comment: Of course it is. I am mainly thinking about future, junior devs who will maintain the code. After all, since this is GUI related, the extra cost of `as` is negligible.

Comment: If I know no other code other than `btnCAPTCHA` can call `btnCAPTCHAClick()`, I use `btnCAPTCHA`, not `Sender`. Not saying it's good practice though,  but, pretty "standard" where I work.

Comment: @KenBourassa good point! I don't know how that slipped my mind when I wrote that example. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

just make a variable like `fhitcount : intger;`

on form create you put this code `fhitcount := 3;`

onclick event this code.

```
begin
  fhitcount := fhitcount-1;
  if fhitcount = 0 then
    begin
      //do what you want and set fhitcount := 3; 
    end;
end;
```

so every time the onclick event is triggerd the fhitcount integer goes down with -1.
when he hits 0 then he activates the next code and resets the fhitcount to 3. if you want.

Comment: Why `fhitcount` to count the times the button has been clicked?  Why not `fclickcount`?

Comment: there is not really a reason to use 'fhitcount' but I use that always when I use counts in my code. It's what you prefer.

Comment: I always prefer `<= 0` over only `= 0` because even if stupid things happen before (not setting it to `3`) I will act upon a threshold instead of only one specific case. And if the code is idiot proof it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Yo thanks this actually worked, thanks alot

Comment: @Haroshi can you mark this answer as the right one? if this is the answer that helped you.